# Proving a sequence is a Cauchy sequence using definition

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am intending to show that the sequence $<f_n>$ where $f_n$ = $ 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}........+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence using the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

My attempt: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $n>m$

$|f_n-f_m|=|\frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m+2}........\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}|$

I am stuck here for how do I find a particular m for each $\epsilon>0$ such that the conditions required for being a Cauchy sequence is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(n-m)$ is odd, we may assume $m$ is even without loss of generality, since $\left\lvert k \right\rvert = \left\lvert -k \right\rvert$. Then \begin{align*}\left\lvert f_n - f_m\right\rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{1}{m+2} + \frac{1}{m+3} - \frac{1}{m+4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}\right\rvert \\ &= \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{1}{m+2} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}\end{align*} since we can see that each pair of terms, of the form $\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)$, is positive, and the final term, $\frac{1}{n}$, is also positive, so the whole expression inside the absolute value signs is positive. Now, we can rewrite this as \begin{align*}\left\lvert f_n - f_m \right\rvert = \frac{1}{m+1} + \left(\frac{1}{m+3}-\frac{1}{m+2}\right) + \dotsb + \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\end{align*} where each bracket is clearly negative (or zero), from which it follows that \begin{equation*}\left\lvert f_n - f_m \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{m+1} \leq \frac{1}{m}\end{equation*}
In the case where $(n-m)$ is even, again assume $m$ is even without loss of generality. We can now re-use our working above, as we have \begin{align*}\left\lvert f_n - f_m \right\rvert &= \left\lvert f_{n} - f_{m+1} + f_{m+1} - f_{m}\right\rvert \\ &\leq \left\lvert f_{n} - f_{m+1}\right\rvert + \left\lvert f_{m+1}-f_{m}\right\rvert \qquad \text{(by the triangle inequality)} \\ &= \left\lvert f_{n} - f_{m+1}\right\rvert + \frac{1}{m+1} \\ &\leq \frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+1} \qquad \text{(by the above working, as $(n-(m+1))$ is odd)} \\ &\leq \frac{2}{m}\end{align*}

Since $\frac{1}{m} \leq \frac{2}{m}$, it follows that you can make $\left\lvert f_n - f_m \right\rvert$ less than any desired $\epsilon > 0$ by taking $n > m > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, so you are done.

Comment: =$|f_n−f_{m+1}|+\frac{1}{m+1}≤\frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{1}{m+1}$(by the above working, as (n−(m+1)) is odd).Here the inequality must be " < " since n-(m+1) is odd and hence $|f_n-f_{m+1}|\le\frac{1}{m+2}$ which is strictly smaller than $\frac{1}{m+1}. Please verify if I am analysed correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but you don't need the strict inequality. $\left\lvert f_n - f_m \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+1} = \frac{2}{m+1} \leq \frac{2}{m}$ is a good enough bound. $\frac{1}{m+2} + \frac{1}{m+1}$, instead of $\frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+1}$, would be a better bound, which would allow you to replace $\frac{2}{\epsilon}$ by something smaller, but that's not necessary.